# Como implementar Ajax en mi codigo

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, pdo

Tengo una duda es que quiero implementar ajax a mi codigo es un CRUD en PHP y MySQL(PDO), lo que ocurre es que de la manera que lo hice no se si lo pueda implementar.
Aqui va mi arquitectura primera (orden de carpetas)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de eso queria implementar el ajax pero no me funciona y realmente no se muy bien como aplicarlo a mi proyecto, e visto varios videos pero estos tienen una arquitectura bastante diferente a la mia. Aquí va el codigo.

```
<?php
include 'model/conexion.php';
$sentencia = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM productos;");
$producto = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.6/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <form action="controllers/insertar.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validar();">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="inputPassword4">Producto</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="producto" id="producto">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputAddress2">Codigo</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputAddress2">Valor unidad</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="valor_unidad" id="valor_unidad">
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="inputAddress2">Stock</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="stock" id="stock">
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="oculto" value="1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>

  <table id="table" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Codigo</th>
        <th>Producto</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Valor Unidad</th>
        <th>Valor total</th>
        <th>Opciones</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
      $i = 1;
      foreach ($producto as $dato) {
      ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $dato->codigo; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $dato->producto; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $dato->stock; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $dato->valor_unidad; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $dato->stock * $dato->valor_unidad . '$'; ?></td>
          <td> <a class="btn btn-success" id="edit" href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $dato->id; ?>">Editar</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" id="del" href="controllers/eliminar.php?id=<?php echo $dato->id; ?>">Eliminar</a>
          </td>

        </tr>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="ventana"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Editar">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.6/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/validaciones.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var table = $('#table').DataTable({
        orderCellsTop: true,
        fixedHeader: true
      });

    });

    $(document).on("click", "#del", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (window.confirm("¿Esta seguro de borrarlo?")) {
        var del_id = $(this).attr("value");

        $.ajax({
          url: "controllers/eliminar.php",
          type: "get",
          data: {
            del_id: del_id
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $("#table").html(data);
          }
        });
      } else {
        return false;
      }

    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Como ven en la parte del script queria implementar ajax y que se me cargue la pagina sin necesidad de reinciarla, lo mismo quiero hacer para el editar y ponerlo en un modal pero primero quiero ver puedo hacerlo funcionar en el eliminar.

Comment: Saludos. Verifica; al parecer (en tu caso) el `jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js` no incluye `ajax`.

Comment: Gracias ese era el error, me di cuenta despues de que publico jejeej gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se soluciono este error llamando bien el jquery ya que me lanzaba un error en el javascript.

Comment: El error era que estaba poniendo jquery.slim y debia poner jquery.min